# MacOS - Toggle wifi when screen unlocked

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I think this will need a combination of AppleScript and Automator, but I don't have much experience in either and Google has been no help. This is basically what I want to do:

```
WHEN screen unlocked (from screensaver, not sleep) THEN
   IF wifi is NOT connected THEN
      Turn wifi off
      Turn wifi back on again
   END IF
END
```

Suggestions?

Comment: To check WiFi state and turn it off/on you can use a [small command line script](https://osxdaily.com/2011/05/31/enable-disable-airport-wireless-connections-command-line/). I don't know how to run it when screensaver ends though. What do you want to do it for, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: I thought so. The machine uses a wifi hotspot that isn't always in situ. If the hotspot is taken away when the screen is locked, then brought back later, the mac doesn't always see the hotspot immediately upon unlocking. The solution is to turn wifi off then back on again.